# Is Redis the right choice for this model

Tags: database-design, redis

I am having a following model:

```
| string (unique key) | about 10 other strings, that have all a fixed length and may be empty |
```

On commonly query is using the 'unique key and see the other strings'. This should be fine using Redis.

But another query is 'show me the keys where column n is empty'. I am not sure if Redis can handle this performant!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this in redis, you will need to maintain some meta data.  One solution would be to add a set type key for each "column" that would hold the unique keys of all elements where that "column" is blank.  Obviously, in your application logic, you will need to add and remove unique keys from these sets as you add and remove values in your main hash.  This will be very fast, as the set operations `sadd`, `srem` and `sismember` are all O(1) for single items (i.e. not proportional to the size of the set).  To get all keys where a "column" is empty, you can use `smembers`.  At least, that's how I've solved similar problems.

(I put quotes around columns since in the redis model, they will be hash fields, not columns as you think of them in an RDBMS)

Comment: Thanks. O(1) sounds perfect! Do you think Redis is a good choice for this problem?

Comment: Really depends on your problem.  The trade off between redis & an RDBMS is flexible storage vs flexible querying.  In redis, it's hard to query on arbitrary fields - you either need to get everything and filter in your app, or build an index like I described in the answer.  On the other hand, it's very easy to add fields, even fields that only exist on some items.  Really depends where you need flexibility.  I like working with it, but I do have a ton of code maintaining indexes with various filters & orderings.